# Should i disconnect/reconnect to MySQL server often?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, timeout

My case is that i have an application made with java that [by now] connects only once to MySQL server and keeps connected. It sends queries to MySQL randomly and it can stay many hours without sending a single query to it, then when it tries to send it again, JDBC says:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was60314 seconds ago.The last packet sent successfully to the server was 60314 seconds ago, which  is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

Then i have many solutions in mind:
- Connect/disconnect every time the app does a query [but it also can make many queries in a second]
- Set that autoReconnect property to 'true' and reconnect when it gets the timeout.
Personaly i like the 2nd. But here's when my question pops out: Is it recommended to do short connections? or it really doesn't matter? Why does MySQL Server keep a wait_timeout property?

Comment: Is this a stand alone application (e.g swing) or a server side one (e.g an application running on tomcat)?

Comment: It's a server side one. Thank you for your answer, i think i will use it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best if you leave the connection handling to a connection pool. Have a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/

Comment: For the sake of anyone landing on this answer, please take a look at [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/). It has a number of improvements over C3P0.

Answer (score 1):

A connection pool might be one answer, but it depends on your application.

I'd prefer to scope the connections to a logical session, for example, a web request or email message, if that logical session has a reasonable limit on its length.

Opening a new connection at the beginning of a new "logical session", using it, then discarding it is good because it minimises the possible effects of a "bad" or "broken" connection on other sessions.

However, in most cases you won't want to renew your connection on each individual operation. This might be a valid strategy for some scenarios though.

Connection pools usually don't correctly reset the connection between uses (the only correct way of doing this in mysql is sending a com_change_user packet; few APIs support this and fewer applications know about it) and hence state leaks from a previous user, possibly causing unreproducible bugs.